# How to write the following pl/sql block without using Cursor?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I had written a cursor in a pl/sql block. This block taking lot of time if it has more records. 
How to write this without a cursor or Is there any other alternative way that will reduce the time?
Is there any alternative query to perform insert into one table and delete from another table using a single query?

```
DECLARE
      MDLCursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
    BEGIN
      open MDLCursor for
        select dc.dest_id, dc.digits, dc.Effectivedate, dc.expirydate
          from DialCodes dc
         INNER JOIN MDL d
            ON dc.Dest_ID = d.Dest_ID
           AND d.PriceEntity = 1
          join sysmdl_calltypes s
            on s.call_type_id = v_CallType_ID
           and s.dest_id = dc.Dest_ID
           and s.call_type_id not in
               (select calltype_id from ignore_calltype_for_routing)
         order by length(dc.digits) desc, dc.digits desc;
      loop
        fetch MDLCursor
          into v_mdldest_id, v_mdldigits, v_mdlEffectiveDate, v_mdlExpDate;
        insert into tt_pendingcost_temp
          (Dest_ID,
           Digits,
           CCASDigits,
           Destination,
           tariff_id,
           NewCost,
           Effectivedate,
           ExpiryDate,
           previous,
           Currency)
          select v_mdldest_id,
                 Digits,
                 v_mdldigits,
                 Destination,
                 tariff_id,
                 NewCost,
                 Effectivedate,
                 ExpiryDate,
                 previous,
                 Currency
            FROM tt_PendingCost
           where substr(Digits, 1, 2) = substr(v_MDLDigits, 1, 2)
             and instr(Digits, v_MDLDigits) = 1
             and v_mdlEffectiveDate <= effectivedate
             and (v_mdlExpDate > effectivedate or v_mdlExpDate is null);
        if SQL%ROWCOUNT > 0 then
          delete FROM tt_PendingCost
           where substr(Digits, 1, 2) = substr(v_MDLDigits, 1, 2)
             and instr(Digits, v_MDLDigits) = 1
             and v_mdlEffectiveDate <= effectivedate
             and (v_mdlExpDate > effectivedate or v_mdlExpDate is null);
        end if;
        exit when MDLCursor%NOTFOUND;
      end loop;
      close MDLCursor;
    END;
```

Comment: Is `Dest_ID` by any chance the primary key of `tt_PendingCost`?  That would provide a way of improving the performance of the procedure.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have your tables and your data so I can only guess at a couple of things that would be slowing you down.

Firstly, the query used in your cursor has an `ORDER BY` clause in it.  If this query returns a lot of rows, Oracle has to fetch them all and sort them all before it can return the first row.  If this query typically returns a lot of results, and you don't particularly need it to return sorted results, you may find your PL/SQL block speeds up a bit if you drop the `ORDER BY`.  That way, you can start getting results out of the cursor without needing to fetch all the results, store them somewhere and sort them first.

Secondly, the following is the `WHERE` clause used in your `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` and `DELETE FROM ...` statements:

```
    where substr(Digits, 1, 2) = substr(v_MDLDigits, 1, 2)
      and instr(Digits, v_MDLDigits) = 1
      and v_mdlEffectiveDate <= effectivedate
      and (v_mdlExpDate > effectivedate or v_mdlExpDate is null);
```

I don't see how Oracle can make effective use of indexes with any of these conditions.  It would therefore have to do a full table scan each time.

The last two conditions seem reasonable and there doesn't seem a lot that can be done with them.  I'd like to focus on the first two conditions as I think there's more scope for improvement with them.

The second of the four conditions is

```
instr(Digits, v_MDLDigits) = 1
```

This condition holds if and only if `Digits` starts with the contents of `v_MDLDigits`.  A better way of writing this would be

```
Digits LIKE v_MDLDigits || '%'
```

The advantage of using `LIKE` in this situation instead of `INSTR` is that Oracle can make use of indexes when using `LIKE`.  If you have an index on the `Digits` column, Oracle will be able to use it with this query.  Oracle would then be able to focus in on those rows that start with the digits in `v_MDLDigits` instead of doing a full table scan.

The first of the four conditions is:

```
substr(Digits, 1, 2) = substr(v_MDLDigits, 1, 2)
```

If `v_MDLDigits` has length at least 2, and all entries in the `Digits` columns also have length at least 2, then this condition is redundant since it is implied by the previous one we looked at.

I'm not sure why you would have a condition like this.  The only reason I can think why you might have this condition is if you have a functional index on `substr(Digits, 1, 2)`.  If not, I would be tempted to remove this `substr` condition altogether.

I don't think the cursor is what is making this procedure run slowly, and there's no single statement I know of that can insert into one table and delete from another.  To make this procedure speed up I think you just need to tune the queries a bit.